# Display post count on archive page in reverse order

Tags: posts, archives, count

I'm displaying some posts and I want each of them to display a post number. The first post being number 1, the most recent post being 10 (let's say there's 10 posts.)

I'm currently using

```
<?php echo $wp_query->current_post + 1?>
```

Which works except the newest post is 1 and the oldest post is 10. How do I reverse this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give a try to this within a loop

```
<?php 
      echo $wp_query->found_posts - $wp_query->current_post ;
?>
```

`$wp_query->found_posts` gives the **total number of posts found matching the current query parameters**.

So the if there are 20 posts, result for each post should look like this

For 1st post it will display `20`,  i.e. 20-0=20
For 2nd post it will display `19`,   i.e. 20-1=19,
...
...
...
For 12th post it will display `9`,   i.e. 20-11=9, and
For 20th post it will display `1`,   i.e. 20-19=1,

Comment: Hey this works! Thanks so much!